# Сгенерировать csv отчет из pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, csv

Для выгрузки отчета необходимо просуммировать данные по отдельному критерию и далее добавить поле, которое считается по определенной формуле, нужно, чтобы файл сам генерировался и если возможно сам задавал себе путь, так как приложение будет использоваться на разных компьютерах.
Данные обрабатываются данным кодом:

```
таблица_для_выгрузки  = (таблица.groupby([таблица["Столбец_1"]])).sum().reset_index()
таблица_для_выгрузки['Новый_столбец'] = таблица_для_выгрузки.Столбец_2*2
#формула гораздо длиннее, но она линейная
    
df.to_csv(r'путь/имя файла.csv')
```

таблица_для_выгрузки обрабатывается и создается с ней все нормально, проблема с генерацией CSV файла.

Код запускается, но ошибок не выдает.

Приложение в целом строится у меня на Flask и Plotly Dash, если есть идеи, как решить с помощью данных технологий, то вы можете пожалуйста поделится.

Answer (score 1):

```
Код запускается, но ошибок не выдает,
```

Ну и отлично.

```
он не выполняет предыдущие функции, которые прописаны в коде
```

Каких "предыдущих"? Кусок кода вы привели, а где "предыдущие"???

```
загрузка данных в БД
```

Где в вашем коде работа с БД? Если что, текстовый файл (csv) -  это никак не БД.

```
он не выполняет предыдущие функции
```

Вы дебагинг проводили? Что значит "не выполняет"?? Таблица не строиться? Или строиться, но не записывается в файл?  Или нужный столбец не добавляется? Тут не собрание экстрасенсов-угадывателей мыслей.

Если вам нужна помощь -  приведите МИНИМАЛЬНО необходимый воспроизводимый фрагмент кода.

P.S. Когда вам отвечают, ссылаясь на текст вашего сообщения, а вы потом этот текст удаляеете -  это немного нечестно по отношению к отвечающему. Его ответ выглядит безсмысленным.  А уж минусовать ответ после этого - совсем.

Comment: Зачем вы мне так грубите :(? Я подправила вопрос, убрала предложение про функции, так как весь код 300 строк вставлять не хочется. Не поняла что я вам минусовала. Это вы мне заминусовали ответ :/

Comment: После того, как вы чего-то там подправили в вопросе - вообще стало непонятно, чего собственно вы хотите.  Что такое "проблема с генерацией CSV файла" -  наверное мы сами должны догадаться, какая проблема. Про 300 строк кода - я же написал про МИНИМАЛЬНО воспроизводимый фрагмент. Но вы, очевидно, это пропустили мимо ушей, как и другие вопросы. Ну, не нуждаетесь в помощи, считаете вопросы, замечания и указания на некорректность формулировок грубостью  -  дело ваше. А уж каков ваш ОТВЕТ я заминусовал -  я вообще не понял.